# How do I split a multi-line string into multiple lines in python?

Tags: python

I have a multi-line string:

```
inputString = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"
```

I want to have an array, each element will have maximum 2 lines it it as below:

```
outputStringList = ["Line 1\nLine2", "Line3"]
```

Can i convert inputString to outputStringList in python. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: Also, please explain WHY you'd want some lines to be split, but not others. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try to find 2 lines (with lookahead inside it to avoid capturing the linefeed) or only one (to process the last, odd line). I expanded your example to show that it works for more than 3 lines (with a little "cheat": adding a newline in the end to handle all cases:

```
import re

s = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nline4\nline5"
result = re.findall(r'(.+?\n.+?(?=\n)|.+)', s+"\n")

print(result)
```

result:

```
['Line 1\nLine 2', 'Line 3\nline4', 'line5']
```

the "add newline cheat" allows to process that properly:

```
    s = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nline4\nline5\nline6"
```

result:

```
['Line 1\nLine 2', 'Line 3\nline4', 'line5\nline6']
```

Comment: Nice, but not working for `s = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nline4\nline5\nline6"`

Comment: @Frane right! see my edit. Simple and handles all cases, odd, even, ending with newline or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using the [`grouper` itertools recipe](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.grouper) to group any number of lines together.

*Note: you can implement this recipe by hand, or you can optionally install a third-party library that implements this recipe for you, i.e. `pip install more_itertools`.*

**Code**

```
from more_itertools import grouper


def group_lines(iterable, n=2):
    return ["\n".join((line for line in lines if line))
                    for lines in grouper(n, iterable.split("\n"), fillvalue="")]
```

**Demo**

```
s1 = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"
s2 = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine4\nLine5"


group_lines(s1)
# ['Line 1\nLine 2', 'Line 3']

group_lines(s2)
# ['Line 1\nLine 2', 'Line 3\nLine4', 'Line5']

group_lines(s2, n=3)
# ['Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3', 'Line4\nLine5']
```

---

**Details**

`group_lines()` splits the string into lines and then groups the lines by `n` via `grouper`.

```
list(grouper(2, s1.split("\n"), fillvalue=""))
[('Line 1', 'Line 2'), ('Line 3', '')]
```

Finally, for each group of lines, only non-emptry strings are rejoined with a newline character.

See [`more_itertools` docs](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for more details on `grouper`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping I get your logic right - If you want a list of string, each with *at most one* newline delimiter, then the following code snippet will work:

```
# Newline-delimited string
a = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5\nLine 6\nLine 7"
# Resulting list
b = []

# First split the string into "1-line-long" pieces
a = a.split("\n")

for i in range(1, len(a), 2):

    # Then join the pieces by 2's and append to the resulting list
    b.append(a[i - 1] + "\n" + a[i]) 

    # Account for the possibility of an odd-sized list
    if i == len(a) - 2: 
        b.append(a[i + 1])

print(b)

>>> ['Line 1\nLine 2', 'Line 3\nLine 4', 'Line 5\nLine 6', 'Line 7']
```

Although this solution isn't the fastest nor the best, it's easy to understand and it does not involve extra libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post the grouper recipe from the itertools docs as well, but [PyToolz' `partition_all`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.partition_all) is actually a bit nicer.

```
from toolz import partition_all

s = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5"
result = ['\n'.join(tup) for tup in partition_all(2, s.splitlines())]
# ['Line 1\nLine 2', 'Line 3\nLine 4', 'Line 5']
```

---

Here's the `grouper` solution for the sake of completeness:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

# Recipe from the itertools docs.
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

result = ['\n'.join((a, b)) if b else a for a, b in grouper(s, 2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [str.splitlines()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm) to split the full input into lines:

```
>>> inputString = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"
>>> outputStringList = inputString.splitlines()
>>> print(outputStringList)
['Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3']
```

Then, join the first lines to obtain the desired result:

```
>>> result = ['\n'.join(outputStringList[:-1])] + outputStringList[-1:]
>>> print(result)
['Line 1\nLine 2', 'Line 3']
```

Bonus: write a function that do the same, for any number of desired lines:

```
def split_to_max_lines(inputStr, n):
    lines = inputStr.splitlines()
    # This define which element  in the list become the 2nd in the
    # final result. For n = 2, index = -1, for n = 4, index = -3, etc.
    split_index = -(n - 1)
    result = ['\n'.join(lines[:split_index])]
    result += lines[split_index:]
    return result

print(split_to_max_lines("Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nline 4\nLine 5\nLine 6", 2))
print(split_to_max_lines("Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nline 4\nLine 5\nLine 6", 4))
print(split_to_max_lines("Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nline 4\nLine 5\nLine 6", 5))
```

Returns:

```
['Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nline 4\nLine 5', 'Line 6']
['Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3', 'line 4', 'Line 5', 'Line 6']
['Line 1\nLine 2', 'Line 3', 'line 4', 'Line 5', 'Line 6']
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a maximum of 2 lines" and how you'd hope to achieve that. However, splitting on newlines is fairly simple.

```
'Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3'.split('\n')
```

This will result in:

```
['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3']
```

To get the weird allowance for "some" line splitting, you'll have to write your own logic for that.

Answer (score -2):

```
b = "a\nb\nc\nd".split("\n", 3)
c = ["\n".join(b[:-1]), b[-1]]
print c
```

gives

```
['a\nb\nc', 'd']
```